# PHP, PDO, Can't get my BETWEEN parameters to register or prepare, get 0 rows

Tags: php, pdo, between

I have this project where I'm converting the old MySQL stuff to PDO. I haven't written a line of PHP  in over 7 years, but I'm doing OK on upgrading this project over the last 2 weeks, still rusty on a few things in PHP and MySQL.

My question or problem is that I can't get the parameters :startLetter and :stopLetter to register or prepare in PDO. The :partnerID works fine.

If I hard code it as a test, BETWEEN \'0\' AND \'Z\' it works fine.
I did hard code the values in the array below as a test, and I did test the variables as well. I did a search and everyone has pretty much the same thing below.

I'm stumped!

```
$lc_query = 
'SELECT DISTINCT m.image_file, m.manufacturer' .
' FROM product p' .
' INNER JOIN manufacturer m' .
' ON p.mfg_id = m.mfg_id' .
' INNER JOIN products pp' .
' ON p.prod_id = pp.prod_id' .
' WHERE m.manufacturer BETWEEN \'0\' AND \'Z\' ' .
//' WHERE m.manufacturer BETWEEN :startLetter AND :stopLetter ' .
' AND pp.p_id = :partnerID' .
' AND p.avail_type < 3' .
' ORDER BY m.manufacturer';    

$lc_params = array(
    //':startLetter' => $lc_alphastart . ', PDO::PARAM_STR',
    //':stopLetter' =>  $lc_alphaend . ', PDO::PARAM_STR',
    ':partnerID' => $go_sitedict['partner_id'] . ', PDO::PARAM_INT'
);
```

Comment: `var_dump($lc_alphastart);` ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can specify the parameter type when using an array to bind during `PDOStatement->execute`. All parameters are considered to be string. You would be essentially binding the full string `0, PDO::PARAM_STR` as the start letter and same for stop letter. You can either use `PDOStatement->bindParam` to bind individual values and specify the value type or just let PDO treat it as a string when passing an array to `->execute` (which is generally just fine as pretty much every type can implicitly convert to string which means that `'0'==0`, even in sql).

So it becomes:

```
$lc_query = 
'SELECT DISTINCT m.image_file, m.manufacturer' .
' FROM product p' .
' INNER JOIN manufacturer m' .
' ON p.mfg_id = m.mfg_id' .
' INNER JOIN products pp' .
' ON p.prod_id = pp.prod_id' .
//' WHERE m.manufacturer BETWEEN \'0\' AND \'Z\' ' .
' WHERE m.manufacturer BETWEEN :startLetter AND :stopLetter ' .
' AND pp.p_id = :partnerID' .
' AND p.avail_type < 3' .
' ORDER BY m.manufacturer';    

$lc_params = array(
    ':startLetter' => $lc_alphastart,
    ':stopLetter' =>  $lc_alphaend,
    ':partnerID' => $go_sitedict['partner_id']
);

//and to execute query...
$stmt=$DB_Connection->prepare($lc_sql);
$stmt->execute($lc_params);
```

Comment: +1 and declaring parameter types doesn't matter anyway. Except for `PDO::PARAM_NULL`, the PDO code doesn't pay any attention to the type.

Comment: @webbiedave thanks. Fixed. I generally use the `->execute` method so I guessed just from memory.